# Anaconda: how to install packages not in Anaconda Directory?

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, conda

Partially related to this question [now removed from SO] but now focus solely on installing packages in Anaconda that does not exist in Anaconda directory [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=clp). An example could be the COIN-OR CLP package [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp) that has interfaces in R [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clpAPI/clpAPI.pdf) and Python [here](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP). I want to make the COIN-OR CLP packages available to the Python/R clients in Anaconda.

**What is the proper way of installing packages in Anaconda not existing in its directory?**

---

*Alternative 1.* Installation of [Coin-MP](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/coinmp) containing the COIN-OR CLP but

```
$ conda install coinmp
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - coinmp
```

*Alternative 2.* Installation from sources causes the error such that

```
svn co https://projects.coin-or.org/svn/CoinMP/stable/1.7 CoinMP
cd CoinMP
./configure -C
...
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
```

with both COIN-MP and COIN-OR CLP.

Comment: I have the same problem with p5 that provides *processing* functionality for python; I could install it with **pip install p5 --user** but I can't use it from within anaconda. As p5 also isn't availabel from conda-forge, the answer below doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

The channel `conda-forge` provides a compiled version. Install by specifying this channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge coinmp
```

Comment: Thank you! Addendum: you can find the channel by searching for the package on [the Anaconda site](https://anaconda.org/search). See also the [Anaconda cheat sheet](https://hcc-docs.unl.edu/download/attachments/11635088/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) for more commands.